# Not able to create promotions through Targeting tab of SDL Tridion

Tags: 2013-sp1, smarttarget, ambient-data-framework

I have everything(CM,CD, Fredhopper) installed on a single system for a java based environment. I have done all the configuration. While creating the new promotion through Targeting Tab I am getting error message showing

```
    An error occurred while processing this request.
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?> <error xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/06/edmx" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata"> 
<code></code> 
<message xml:lang="en-US">The appropriate post claim has not been set.</message> </error>
```

Detailed error message is:

```
at Tridion.Web.UI.Models.SmartTarget.Services.SavePromotion(String publicationTargetId, String promotionXml)
   at SyncInvokeSavePromotion(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
   at Tridion.Web.UI.Core.Extensibility.DataExtenderOperationInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
```

Can anyone suggest the possible root cause of the error. Thanks in advance..

Comment: Does the OData webservice  between the CM and Fredhopper work at all? Can you access that URL in the browser? Does it show you the metadata of the service?

Comment: Hi Albert, Yes it is working fine. I can also access all trigger types by accessing url http://localhost:8081/cd_webservice/odata.svc/TriggerTypes. When I publish a component separately with Add to smart target tbb attached in compound template it is also working fine. My fredhopper service is also working fine.

Comment: In CD_Core log of Odata webservice it is showing warning "AmbientDataContext - There is no current ambient data context - the ambient data framework is not properly initialised". This is the only log file where I can see something unusual. Can anyone suggest if this may be the reason of issue I am facing. Also can you suggest what configuration I am missing..

Comment: The error suggest that the OData service (SmartTarget Web service) between the CM and Fredhopper isn't configured correctly. Doublecheck it by following these steps (again): http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_SmartTarget_2014_SP1-v1/GUID-C46FC390-C929-418D-9B11-AB052EF3CF0E

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"The appropriate post claim has not been set." means that there isn't a claim in the Ambient Data Framework that specifically allows write operations in the OData web service.

This claim is added by the `smarttarget_odata_cartridge.jar` file.

So make sure that you've installed it properly (see [Installing SmartTarget Web service](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_SmartTarget_2014_SP1-v1/GUID-0786BCA2-047C-4C77-93BD-CDD7736DA920)) and that your Ambient Data Framework is running correctly on said Web service.

Comment: Odata service was not configured correctly. I have compared my odata service for experience manager and for smart target and found some differences between them. By removing those differences and following link provided by Peter and Albert issue seems to be fixed. I am able to create promotions now. Thanks..